# (ExceptionInInitializerError) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class PluginContextListener

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created one portlet and i am trying to do deploy, but while doing deployment, I am getting the following error,

**Note:I am using liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ce-ga6**

Please help me out.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployEvent.initDependentServletContextNames(HotDeployEvent.java:97)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployEvent.<init>(HotDeployEvent.java:53)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireUndeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:170)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalDestroy(PluginContextListener.java:132)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalDestroy(BasePortalLifecycle.java:31)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextDestroyed(PluginContextListener.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1028)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deleteRedeployResources(HostConfig.java:1299)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1229)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1439)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:315)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil.get(PropsUtil.java:32)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.DependencyManagementThreadLocal.<clinit>(DependencyManagementThreadLocal.java:40)
... 21 more

May 27, 2016 2:21:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/Sample-portlet] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CentralizedThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMapThreadLocal] (value [com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CentralizedThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMapThreadLocal@32b11adf]) and a value of type [com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CentralizedThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap] (value [com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CentralizedThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap@95b4079]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: Is this on first deployment or on redeploy? (The last line of your log suggests that it's on redeploy, when the previously deployed version is shut down before the next one comes in) It also might help to see some code - please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yeah its redeployment,and i just created the portlet ,nothing i have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a while I found that this type of error comes sometimes when you have duplicated the `portal-service.jar` so make sure this dendency in your pom is set to `provided`

Comment: Thank you KLajdPaja,I dont know what was the exact problem but my problem was solved,these are the below steps I did 1)Removed the all jar files from tomcat/lib ext folder. (2).once again cleared and re deployed the portal (3)Restarted the server now its working fine